# What happened to the first nine Weapon programmes?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

Wolverine was created in the Weapon X program (in fact he *became* Weapon X). Does this mean there were nine other attempts at bonding adamantium to a skeleton, or does it mean there were 9 other separate projects designed at making a weapon?

Comment: [Or even 23!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X) Wolverine wasn’t made by the Romans. (Now *there’s* a *What If* I’d like to read. Victis honor, bub.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Weapons Plus program deals with various experiments - mostly genetic in nature. While adamantium has figured into some of the experiments, it is not a primary component.

---

**Comic Continuity** (Primarily [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-616), but some projects from alternate futures have time traveled and become involved with the main timeline)

- **Weapon 0**: The precursor to Project Rebirth. Began as a collaborative effort between US, British and German scientists. The project splintered once WW2 began. No details have been revealed regarding exact test subjects or results. [Dr. Josef Reinstein](http://marvel.wikia.com/Abraham_Erskine_%28Earth-616%29) defected to the US and took the name Dr. Abraham Erskine.
- **Weapon I**: (AKA: Project Rebirth) - Resulted in the creation of [Captain America](http://marvel.com/universe/Captain_America_%28Steve_Rogers%29), [Isaiah Bradley](http://marvel.com/universe/Bradley,_Isaiah), and [Protocide](http://marvel.wikia.com/Clinton_McIntyre_%28Earth-616%29) as well as a number of failed experiments. Captain America's original [shield](http://marvel.com/universe/Captain_America%27s_Shield) was made of an adamantium steel-vibranium alloy. Dr. Erskine was one of the primary scientists involved.
- **Weapon II**: Genetic experimentation on various animals, such as [this squirrel](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_II_(Earth-616)) which did appear to have an adamantium skeleton and claws, as well as an enhanced healing factor.
- **Weapon III**: Experimentation on [Skinless Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/Weapon_III_%28Earth-616%29), a mutant with elastic skin.
- **Weapon IV**: More experimentation on animals.
- **Weapons V & VI**: Experimentation on various ethnic minorities.
- **Weapon VII**: (AKA: Project Homegrown) Experimentation on soldiers in Vietnam. Attempts made at adamantium bonding.  [Nuke](http://marvel.com/universe/Nuke) was the only known success of Project Homegrown, but [Cyber](http://marvel.com/universe/Cyber) may have been one of the subjects to undergo adamantium bonding tests. The UK had its own version of Project: Homegrown called *The Black Budget*. Both it and The Mercy Corporation (an offshoot of SHIELD) were successful at creating their own super-soldiers.
- **Weapon VIII & IX**: Experimentation on criminals and psychopaths.
- **Weapon X**: Experimentation on mutants. [Wolverine](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine), [Sabretooth](http://marvel.com/universe/Sabretooth) and [Deadpool](http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool) are the most notable subjects. Adamantium bonding was experimented with, but was not the sole focus of the experiments. Once dissolved, Weapon X became Department K in Canada.
- **Weapon XI**: Unknown, however Rob Liefeld has [made comments](http://www.cbr.com/rob-liefeld-looks-back-on-deadpools-real-secret-origin/) implying that [Garrison Kane](http://marvel.com/universe/Kane,_Garrison) was intended to be Weapon XI. Kane would later become part of the Weapon X program thanks to time travel and even uses the name "Weapon X".
- **Weapon XII**: Experimentation creating an AI with nanosentinel technology to be part of the Super-Sentinels. Resulted in the creation of [Huntsman](http://marvel.wikia.com/Zona_Cluster-6_%28Earth-616%29).
- **Weapon XIII**: Further experimentation with nanosentinel technology, resulting in the creation of [Fantomex](http://marvel.com/universe/Fantomex).
- **Weapon XIV**: Experimentation on [the Stepford Cuckoos](http://marvel.com/universe/Stepford_Cuckoos), a set of quintuplets with telepathic powers.
- **Weapon XV**: Experimentation to create a high powered super-sentinel. Resulted in the creation of [Ultimaton](http://marvel.com/universe/Ultimaton).
- **Weapon XVI**: Resulted in creation of a super-powered virus known as "[Allgod](http://marvel.wikia.com/Weapon_XVI)", which enslaves anyone it infects.
- **Weapon Infinity**: (AKA [Project Deathlok](http://www.comicvine.com/deathlok-legion/4060-58246/)) - Experimentation in reanimation of corpses of soldiers and superheroes. Resulted in the creation of an army of reanimated soldiers.
- **The Facility**: Not technically part of the "Weapons Plus" programs, [The Facility](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Facility_(Earth-616)) was an unaffiliated program aiming to recreate the results of the Weapon X program. In specific, they were attempting to bond adamantium to skeletons. When all of their attempts failed, they turned to genetic cloning, resulting in [Laura Kinney (X-23)](http://marvel.com/universe/X-23).

---

**Fox/X-Men Movie Continuity** ([Earth-10005](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-10005))

<sup>Note that this is sort of a giant cluster#### and makes very little sense.</sup>

- **Weapon Null/0**: This project exists only in a novel based off of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, and should be considered non-canon. An early super-soldier program focused on bioenhancing soldiers to turn them into self-contained organic weapons. The project was shelved due to excessive costs. Four resulting soldiers were mentioned: Slammer, Blowtorch, Cypher, and Bipolar.
- **Weapon X**: Largely similar to the Earth-616 version of the program. It involved a larger pool of mutants being experimented on. It created [Wolverine](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Howlett_%28Earth-10005%29), [Lady Deathstrike](http://marvel.wikia.com/Yuriko_Oyama_%28Earth-10005%29), [X-23](http://marvel.wikia.com/Laura_Kinney_%28Earth-10005%29), and [Deadpool](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wade_Wilson_%28Earth-10005%29).
- **Weapon XI**: Strangely, prior to the timeline alterations of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Deadpool was referred to **as** "*Weapon XI*". Whether or not the Weapon XI was actually just a branch, side project or a whole new project separate from Weapon X has never been clearly defined.

No other details regarding other "Weapons" programs have been revealed in this continuity.

---

**Marvel Cinematic Universe** ([Earth-19999](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-199999))

- **Project Rebirth**: A cinematic counterpart to *Weapon 1* of the Earth-616 universe, but no "Weapon" designation is ever mentioned. It was largely spearheaded by [Dr. Abraham Erskine](http://marvel.wikia.com/Abraham_Erskine_%28Earth-199999%29).
- **Weapon Plus**: No details have been revealed about exactly who, or what this program experimented on, but the super-soldier serum injected into [Emil Blonsky](http://marvel.wikia.com/Emil_Blonsky_%28Earth-199999%29) is labeled as being [developed by "Dr. Reinstein"](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/Hybrid0027/news/?a=57712), an alias of Dr. Abraham Erskine in Earth-616. It should be noted that while multiple wiki sites list Reinstein as an alias of Erskine in this continuity, no direct connection has been made in any movie or supplemental material; The connection is being largely assumed based on the Earth-616 facts.

---

Source: mostly a boiled down summation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_Plus). Some cross-referenced info from [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Weapon_Plus) and [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Weapon_Plus_%28Earth-616%29).

Comment: Nice work making this comprehensive list.

Comment: Source(s)? Good list even without

Comment: Isn't Deadpool Weapon XI?

Comment: He is referred to as Weapon XI in X-Men Origins: Wolverine. However, in the comics, Deadpool is just another subject of the Weapon X project.

Comment: Perhaps you should add Isaiah Bradley to the Project Rebirth entry, just a suggestion though this is a very comprehensive list.

Comment: So, basically the Evil Government Conspiracy can only count to 16?

Comment: Also, wow. A virus that “attacks the faith reserves,” and that, according to the wiki, “only atheists” are immune to? Did someone read *Sixth Column* and decide to adapt it for [Hollywood Atheism?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodAtheist)