# Has the Super Soldier serum been successfully reproduced after Rogers?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

After Rogers is turned into Cap, we've heard of several attempts at reproducing the serum, the most recent I think (at least according the MCU) results on the creation of the Hulk.
Is there any case where the serum is successfully reproduced? (mostly asking about the comic universe here)

Thanks

Comment: Yes - http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Abdul_Al-Rahman_(Earth-1610)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Isaiah Bradley](http://marvel.com/universe/Bradley,_Isaiah) was turned into a super-soldier using a serum based on the formula used for Steve Rogers.

[Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Bradley):

> When World War II begins, Koch takes over the German program and Josef Reinstein takes over the American program. Each attempts to recreate the super soldier serum which had previously turned Steve Rogers into Captain America a year prior to Pearl Harbor. Reinstein's early attempts to refine the formula are tested on African-Americans. Three hundred of these soldiers are taken from Camp Cathcart and subjected to potentially fatal experiments at an undisclosed location, as seen in Truth: Red, White & Black. Only five subjects survive the original trials. In the name of secrecy, US soldiers execute the camp's commander and hundreds of black soldiers left behind at Camp Cathcart. The government tells the families of the three hundred subjects that their loved ones had died in battle.

Not only was Bradley successfully turned into a super soldier, he was considered "The Black Captain America."

[image: bradley]

[Nuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuke_%28Marvel_Comics%29) was also successfully* turned into a super-soldier using a serum similar to the one used on Rogers.

*Nuke was also insane, but his mental issues existed prior to the experimentation on him.

[image: nuke]

It should be noted that the Weapons Plus programs were born from the original super-soldier experimentation. Each of the programs was aimed at weaponizing or augmenting people in various ways, but not all of them involved serums, derived from Erskine's or not. There is some more information about this [in "What happened to the first nine Weapon programmes?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14006/5184).

Comment: Isaiah and his crew were a mixed success. He suffered from early dementia and the other members of his squad suffered from deformities and mental illness. Really, that's been the pattern of things. Captain America is unusual because he's both not deformed (when not drawn by Liefeld) and not crazy.

Answer (score 4):

In the regular 616 continuity, it's never been reproduced the exact same way. This is because Captain America needs to stay unique, as a character. Either it can't be reproduced, or it's reproduced in a way that causes some unforeseen drawback. There are other stories where it is reproduced or similar formulas are made. My favorite of these is a What If: [image]

It's been a while since I read this. From what I remember, in the story, Captain America manages to kill the assassin before he kills Erskine. 
So, (almost) everyone in America gets the super soldier serum. It's a fun read.

Answer (score -1):

Since Steve was the original icon of the "Super Soldier", it wouldn't be inaccurate to state that every program, every mad scientist, and every rouge or secret government agency that intentionally produces a metahuman soldier and/or weapon is a direct recreation of the Super Soldier Serum. In that case, every superhero who got their powers from Wolverine, Spider-Man, or the Hulk can be considered successful reproductions of the original Super Soldier Serum. In each case, someone thought of a new angle to the original S3. Osborn (or Doc. Oc.) thought of using animal DNA, Weapon X thought of simply adapting the already empowered mutant DNA, and anyone who's ever seen the Hulk in action just decides to pump Gamma into someone and see what happens.

Comment: Also, the Mutant Growth Hormone (MGH)- a.k.a. Inhuman Growth Hormone (IGH)- is basically a short-term version of the Super Soldier Serum- albeit brief, addictive, random, and often lethal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any meaningful way. We're not looking for unsuccessful, partial or indirect replications .